# New co-ordinates for every 10 images in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach, gd, coordinates

I have this foreach loop

```
foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $key) {         

   $bricks_to_choose = mt_rand(1,1);

   $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $key[0]."".$bricks_to_choose.".png"); 
   imagecopy($img, $cur, $coords, 0, 0, 0, 125, 30); 

   $coords += 132;
}
```

How can I for every 10, every 20, every 30 etc. images set new coordinates?

It should output 10 images in one row starting at x = 0 and y = 0, the 11th image will then start at x = 0 and y = 37

The 21st image will then be placed at x = 0, y = 74 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be quite simple.  The code below may not be the most optimal, but it's easy to understand.

```
$dx = 132;
$dy = 37;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$perrow = 20;
$cnt = 1;

foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $key) {         

    $bricks_to_choose = mt_rand(1,1);

    $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $key[0]."".$bricks_to_choose.".png"); 
    imagecopy($img, $cur, $x, $y, 0, 0, 125, 30);

    $x += dx;

    if(++$cnt % $perrow == 0) {
        $x = 0;
        $y += dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: This places the images in a staircase pattern. 1 at each row

Comment: @MortenHagh Just saw your comment and realised my mistake.  Please see the updated code: increment of `$y` needs to happen together with assigning 0 to `$x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $key) {         

   $bricks_to_choose = mt_rand(1,1);

   $ycords = (floor(($i++) / 10) * 37);

   $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $key[0]."".$bricks_to_choose.".png"); 
   imagecopy($img, $cur, $coords, $ycords, 0, 0, 125, 30); 

   $coords += 132;
}
```

This should work.

Note the `$ycords = (floor(($i++) / 10) * 37);` line.

**Edit**:
Of course, if you don't want any X positioning, change `$coords` for `0`